# Create a style for a title

Tags: titles

I need to create some kind of title style that must not appear into the TOC and must looks like this, maybe more close to the paragraph.

[image]

I try this,

```
\newcommand{\littt}[1]{
    \begin{flushleft}
    \textbf{#1}
    \end{flushleft}
    \vspace{-1cm}
}
```

but sometimes looks perfect and sometimes appears over the text.

Comment: Have you looked at the `titlesec` package?

Comment: With a class from [KOMA Script](http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) you could simply use the `\minisec` command.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the starred versions of the sectional unit commands (`\chapter*`, `\section*`, and so on). These commands insert the title in the same style as their non-starred equivalent, but they leave out the number and don't appear in the table of contents.

Since the starred versions don't insert the titles in the table of contents, they also don't take an optional argument. The normal (non-starred) versions of the sectional unit commands *do* take an option, which they insert into the table of contents instead of the regular (mandatory) argument.

```
\chapter*{Nested Lists}

{\LaTeX} will happily, \ldots.
```

[Chapter Title: Nested Lists http://csweb.ucc.ie/~dongen/TeX-SX/11--12/nested-list.png](http://csweb.ucc.ie/~dongen/TeX-SX/11--12/nested-list.png)

```
\chapter[Wales]%
        {My Amazingly Amusing Adventures in
         Llanfairpwllgwyngyllgogerychw%
         yrndrobwllllantysiliogogogoch}
```

[Short Chapter Title: Wales http://csweb.ucc.ie/~dongen/TeX-SX/11--12/wales.png](http://csweb.ucc.ie/~dongen/TeX-SX/11--12/wales.png)

Answer (score 1):

Creating your own style is not that difficult. The following minimal example provides `\littt{<stuff>}` that typesets `<stuff>` in `\large\bfseries` and adds a vertical `\bigskip` between the "title" and the "body". It also prepares the following paragraph to have `\noindent`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\littt}[1]{%
  \noindent{\large\bfseries #1}\par\nobreak%
  \kern\bigskipamount\nobreak\noindent\ignorespaces
}
\begin{document}
\littt{Nested Lists}
LaTeX will happily \ldots
\end{document}
```

The addition of `\nobreak` discourages page breaks between the "title" and "body". Moreover, since this does not use sectional commands, it won't make its way into the ToC. Reducing the space is also possible by choosing a different value to `\kern` (for example, `\medskipamount` or `\smallskipamount`, or any TeX length for that matter.

Of course, more modifications are also possible (like specifying local changes via an optional argument, for example).